# Eclipse: is it possible to debug a method called by an CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, lambda

I have this code:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> addReferenceAnyBrowser(referenceManagementTestPageSafari));
```

Putting a breakpoint here works without a problem.

However, when I put a breakpoint in the method addReferenceAnyBrowser, nothing happens. Is this expected behavior?

Java 8 is already there for quite some time so I expect Eclipse to be able to debug lambdas also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse also supports breakpoints at methods called from a Lambda function, as you can verify with the following example:

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> foo());
        future.get();
    }

    private static void foo() {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }

}
```

In your case, this means that an instance of `CompletableFuture` has been created, but the Lambda function has not yet been executed because **`get()` has not yet been called ([lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation))**.